# Can someone explain producer and consumer in P V form?

Tags: algorithm, semaphore, producer-consumer

[Wikipedia has a sample code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29#Example%3a_Producer.2Fconsumer_problem) that everyone uses.

I honestly don't get the P,V thing.

It first said

> The consumer must wait for the producer to produce something if the
>   queue is empty.

But then it said

> Example. A single consumer enters its critical section. Since
>   fullCount is 0, the consumer blocks.

I assume blocking means waiting? My homework requires me to understand the use of such binary semaphore and then implement a solution for a different kind of producer-consumer problem. But I don't get when to increment (which shared variable to set in P and V) or decrement. So I hope someone knowledgeable can explain to me? Treat me like a non-cs student if you may?

Comment: Have you read the [Producer-consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) page linked from the Semaphore page?  It may answer your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine a couple guys moving into a house.

They have a truck full of boxes they need to offload into the house.

So they decide to split up the work.

- Paul Producer says he'll take boxes off the truck and line them up
  on the sidewalk.
- Charlie Consumer says he'll takes boxes off the sidewalk and take
  them into house.

It works well for a while. But then Peter shows up, and he offers to
help brother Paul. Suddenly, the sidewalk fills up with boxes before
Charlie can pick them up. He gets bummed about this and calls brothers
Conrad and Carl.  But Conrad hurt his arm and Carl keeps playing with
his phone, so now:

- Sometimes the producers (paul, peter) still outpace the consumers,
  the sidewalk is full and the guys have to stand around holding boxes
- Sometimes the consumers (charlie, conrad, carl) outpace the producers
  and they're standing around the sidewalk instead of unpacking in house

So everyone makes a rule: check the sidewalk before you go there!

Unfortunately, it didn't help. Paul and Peter, emptying opposite ends
of the truck, both saw an almost full sidewalk, but clearly enough
space for one more box. So they both picked off a box, walked over,
then bonked into each other (race condition!).

Finally Quincy Queue shows up. He makes three new rules:

1. Paul/Peter: you both have to check with me to make sure there's
   an empty spot before you dropoff:
2. Conrad/Carl/Charlie: you have to check with me to make
   sure there's a box before you pick up:
3. And finally, because there's only one of me, I can't keep track
   of this if more than one guy is messing with the line.So even
   if I gave you a green light in step 1 or 2, you still need to
   check to make sure no one else is on the line.

So Peter/Paul's final rules become:

```
waitFor(spaceOnSideWalk)
waitFor(permissionToUseSideWalk))
dropBoxOnSidewalk(box)
nowSomeoneElseCanUse(permissionToUseSideWalk))
nowSomeoneElseCanUse(boxesOnSideWalk)
```

(and Charlie/Carl/Conrad complementary)

If you think of

```
waitFor == decrement == P
nowSomeoneElseCanUse == increment == V
```

Then you'll have exactly the alogrithm on the wikipedia page.

Comment: thanks. very clear! very helpful. now i am getting at this. i still come back and read it as a reference :D

Answer (score 1):

If the fullCount semaphore is 0 and the consumer executes P(fullCount) it will block (wait) until a producer increases the semaphore by executing V(fullCount).

P(useQueue) is used by both the consumer and producer to make sure they have the exclusive right to change the queue. After they have done their change they will do V(useQueue) to release the queue again.

If this does not answer your question I think you need to better specify your question.