# Why is my producer-consumer blocking?

Tags: c, algorithm, unix, semaphore, producer-consumer

My code is here: http://pastebin.com/Fi3h0E0P

Here is the output

```
0
Should we take order today (y or n): y
Enter order number: 100
More customers (y or n): n

Stop serving customers right now. Passing orders to cooker:
There are total of 1 order(s)
1
Roger, waiter. I am processing order #100
```

The goal is waiter must take orders and then give them to the cook. The waiter has to wait cook finishes all pizza, deliver the pizza, and then take new orders.

I asked how P-V work in my previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374397/can-someone-explain-producer-and-consumer-in-p-v-form).

I don't think it has anything to do with `\n` consuming? I tried all kinds of combination of `wait()`, but none work.

Where did I make a mistake?

The main part is here:

```
//Producer process
 if(pid > 0)
 {
    while(1)
    {
      printf("0");
      P(emptyShelf); // waiter as P finds no items on shelf;
      P(mutex); // has permission to use the shelf
      waiter_as_producer();
      V(mutex); // cooker now can use the shelf
      V(orderOnShelf); // cooker now can pickup orders

      wait();
      printf("2");
      P(pizzaOnShelf);
      P(mutex);
      waiter_as_consumer();
      V(mutex);
      V(emptyShelf);
      printf("3 ");
    }
 }
    if(pid == 0)
    {
     while(1)
    {
     printf("1");
     P(orderOnShelf); // make sure there is an order on shelf
     P(mutex); //permission to work
     cooker_as_consumer(); // take order and put pizza on shelf
     printf("return from cooker");
     V(mutex); //release permission
     printf("just released perm");
     V(pizzaOnShelf); // pizza is now on shelf
     printf("after");
     wait();
     printf("4");

    }
  }
```

So I imagine this is the execution path:
enter waiter_as_producer, then go to child process (cooker), then transfer the control back to parent, finish waiter_as_consumer, switch back to child. The two waits switch back to parent (like I said I tried all possible wait() combination...).

Comment: Which of the wait operations do the respective processes block on?

Comment: Also, what does `wait()` do? If it's the POSIX function, it shouldn't really be necessary - `P()` and maybe `V()` should do the waiting.

Comment: and this is the header file http://pastebin.com/4Jse4bRg   and P,V are defined at the end.

Comment: @millimoose my bad at throwing so many comments on you. Let me correct myself one last time. It didn't return successfully from `cooker_as_consumer` because the last statement `finished cooking` was not in the output... ah my bad

Comment: Do you have a way to get the actual states of the semaphores as well. It'd also help to put a println before/after every P/V call.

Comment: @millimoose sure let me debug this thoroughly. thanks for helping.

Comment: Add some \n to the printf strings. stdout is line buffered.

Comment: Basically, my rough guess is that the wait() is unnecessary, according to wikipedia the mutex is as well; and the cause of your bug is either `wait()` causing a deadlock as both processes are waiting for the other one to do something, or the initial state of your semaphores being wrong.

Comment: am I supposed to get this kind of number? `emptyShelf state: 4522101
` sorry for being a C noob :(

Comment: Nope, that's probably just the pointer address or handle id. Should be a smallish integer.

Comment: Looking at the header you linked to, it seems to use the braindamaged SysV API. You can get the value of the semaphore using [`semctl()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/semctl) somehow - look at your header file to see how this function is supposed to be used

Comment: @wildplasser thanks. now i can see it stuck after printing '4' even after adding a wait. thanks millimoose. i am working on that...

Comment: hey guys. i have a hard time getting the state out of the union s in the header. can someone help me on getting the state?

Comment: @User007 Deleting the `wait()`s lets me get through multiple orders. They're what's breaking the code and your instructor is probably confused of confusing or both.

Comment: @User007 Here's a Gist with what works for me: https://gist.github.com/4075391

Comment: @millimoose thank you very much sir. I got it :) learned something new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- change to `#define PERMS (0)` (it is **NOT** an octal file mode mask!)
- remove all the `wait();`s
- scale size by sizeof: `if((shmid=shmget(1000,sizeof (int) * BUFSIZE,IPC_CREAT | PERMS)) < 0)` , and others (the size is scaled up modulo semsize/pagesize, but it is a good habit to use the right size anyway)

fixed the problem here.

The whole idea is: you don't *need* to wait; one of the {producer,consumer} will be blocked on a P() somewhere:

from P():

```
sb.sem_flg = 0; /* blocking call */
    if (semop(sid, &sb, 1) == -1)
        perror("semop");
```

And besides: `wait(&status)` needs at least an argument. (and you would probably need one of the other wait functions, such as wait3() or waitpid() )

Extra besides:

- I would put "volatile" before the declarations of the shared objects: `volatile int *buff;`
- main() should return int, returns without a value are wrong (before c99)
- most of the pointer operations are clumsy: `order = buffer[i];` is the same as `order = *(buffer+i);`, but more readable.

Comment: I'm guessing what's in the header is provided by the instructor. My operating systems module also had a pointless wrapper around SysV IPC. (It seems to be a thing amongst OS instructors to teach classes as if they expected students to have to work on pre-POSIX systems.)

Comment: It could be viewed as an exercise to RTFM.

Comment: More like an exercise in abstrusity. There's a reason why that API was abandoned, and that's because it's annoying to use. And if you wanted students to RTFM, you wouldn't give them a header with wrapper functions. Ones that are, as you point out in your answer, actually broken. (At least I wouldn't. I'd point people to the docs for the POSIX API and teach the course using those calls instead of `P` and `V`.)

Comment: hey guys. Thank you very much. I finished my work. I took your recommendation, wildplasser. I am not the kind of person relying on external help. I tried to resolve this myself, but sometimes when deadline is close and I have no idea what went wrong in my C code I am forced to seek help. But I learned. Thanks to both of you. Next step is to ask people in codereview to tell me whether my implementation is okayish or totally stupid. Obviously this is some really really low-level stuff that even the code is so hard to understand O_O.